# btrfs subvolume delete * not removing snapshots, leading to unbootable system

Tags: btrfs

My system became unbootable, and now I am trying to recover it. It uses 20 GB out of 200 GB partition of btrfs, but is now filled with 4,000 annoying snapshots I can not remove due to "read-only filesystem":

```
btrfs sub list /mnt/kubuntu/@/.snapshots
ID 4360 gen 13915414 top level 4103 path 95/snapshot
ID 4361 gen 13916914 top level 4103 path 96/snapshot
ID 4362 gen 13916950 top level 4103 path 97/snapshot
ID 4363 gen 15326652 top level 4103 path 110/snapshot

btrfs subvolume delete *

ERROR: Not a Btrfs subvolume: Invalid argument
ERROR: Not a Btrfs subvolume: Invalid argument
ERROR: Not a Btrfs subvolume: Invalid argument
ERROR: Not a Btrfs subvolume: Invalid argument
ERROR: Not a Btrfs subvolume: Invalid argument

rm -rf * 
rm: cannot remove '105/snapshot/mnt/WDC640/home_folder/cc/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew/gradle-4.1/src/base-services/org/gradle/internal/service/AbstractServiceMethod.java': Read-only file system

btrfs scrub start /mnt/kubuntu
fstrim -v 
btrfs balance start /mnt/kubuntu
```

Seems like I need to copy all the files off the disk, reformat ext4, and never use btrfs again!

Comment: Alternatively, you could learn to use btrfs properly.   You need to specify the path to the subvolume(s), either relative to your current working directory or an absolute path.  Try `btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/kubuntu/@/.snapshots/*/snapshot`.   Then `btrfs subvolume sync` to wait until the snapshots are completely deleted, followed by scrub and balance if required.   BTW, you probably want to run fstrim **after** balance (instead of, or maybe in addition to running it before the balance).

Comment: and if the filesystem is mounted read-only, you'll have to remount it RW first.

Comment: finally, i very strongly recommend setting up a VM with with two or more virtual disks using btrfs (size is not important, a few hundred MB each is enough) and using that to learn and get familiar with btrfs.   it's not safe to learn on a real system with real data, but a VM is a good, safe environment to make mistakes in.